# iOS update number of views for a video file from server automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

1. Video file loaded from server.
2. Video file has (number of views).
3. If any application user views that particular video the number of views should be incremented and updated.

If I am viewing that video and another user viewed that particular video, is it possible to automatically update the number of views without any user action.

If there is any possible solution AND is a good practice, what is the best approach to implement this using Objective-C?

I've seen some iOS apps updating the number of views for videos which keeps incrementing every second even if the internet connection is disabled, so I think that is a fake counter.

So I was going through a function call every 5 seconds to check the number of views for each video from the server, but I am not sure if it is a good practice, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets are usually great for keeping things updated without any user interaction.

Take a look at this iOS framework: `https://github.com/square/SocketRocket`

There are different approaches to update the view-counter, the safest is if you put a REST-server "in front of the video file", which returns the video file and at the same time updates the number of views in your database.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! can't add plus don't have enough rep.

Comment: You could also look at realtime.co if you need greater scalability

Comment: I will be checking that too as I am testing all possible solutions.